# Prove that using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: integration, analysis

> $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ Prove that
> $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}\left|t\right|\mathrm{d}t=\dfrac{x|x|}{2}$$

First I distinguish the t value with knowing that absolute value act differently for $t \ge 0$ and $t< 0$. So:

$$\displaystyle |t| = \begin{cases} t &\text{if }t \ge 0 \\ -t &\text{if }t < 0 \end{cases}$$
So if we integrate:

$$\displaystyle \int|t|\mathrm{d}t = \begin{cases} \dfrac{t^2}{2} &\text{if } t>0 \\ -\dfrac{t^2}{2} &\text{if }t < 0 \end{cases}$$

And then I plugged the variables. But I didn't get the result. Thanks.

Comment: If $t\ge0$ then $t^2/2=t|t|/2$. If $t<0$ then $-t^2/2=t|t|/2$.

Answer (score 3):

If $x\geqslant 0$, then\begin{align}\int_0^x|t|\,\mathrm dt&=\int_0^xt\,\mathrm dt\\&=\frac{x^2}2\\&=\frac{x|x|}2\end{align}and if $x\leqslant0$, then\begin{align}\int_0^x|t|\,\mathrm dt&=-\int_x^0-t\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_x^0t\,\mathrm dt\\&=-\frac{x^2}2\\&=\frac{x|x|}2.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks I understand, so I did it correctly but I couldnt ended up with this result. Thanks a lot!